# how to pass json body as String in FETCH PUT API in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

how to pass json body as String in FETCH PUT API in react js ? I am trying to 20 addition to the Balance  like this Balance: details[0].Balance.toString() + 20 which didnt work. i want to hve it as string altogether

Any help would be greatly appreciated. please

Below Sample code:

```
fetch(memberput, {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: curHeaders,
  body: JSON.stringify({
  ID:details[0].ID.toString(),
  Balance: details[0].Balance.toString() + 20
  })
  })
  .then(function(response){
    console.log('Final ', response.json());
  })
```

Expectedoutput: If currentbalance is 30, it should give me 30+20 = 50

Actual output: If currentbalance is 30, its giving me 3020 now.

Comment: Also this doesnt work Add: (member[0].count += 20). But when i tried in postman request by hardcoding the value, the below one works {\"count\":\"20"}"

Comment: since your `body` isn't a valid OBJECT, it can't be stringified - this is the same question as yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64520571/react-fetch-put-sum-addition which was closed `Add details and clarify the problem being solved. This will help others answer the question` - yet, you've posted exactly the same question with some vague "comments"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [REACT Fetch PUT - Sum/Addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64520571/react-fetch-put-sum-addition)

Comment: hi, but my other calls work in exactly the same way. only thing here is i am not able to do addition. since my older was closed, created this new post. can you tell me what are the comments which i can give ? sorry new to this.

Comment: Got the error from logs that its expecting str and not int :-) Below is the code 
 count: member[0].count + 20 ~ need to do some addition when doing fetch put api. is there a way i can make it as string and pass it to body?

Comment: First ensure that balance is a number, do not make it to string if so that will be a 3020 and not a 50. So maybe something like Number(balance) + 20.

Comment: First thank you so much for responding. if i do that its getting me the below error:   line 419, in put
    setparams = {'Balance':  '\'' + request.json['Balance'] + '\'',
TypeError: must be str, not int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> String + string = concatenate strings
>
> String + number = concatenate string and number
>
> Number + number = sum of the number

What you should do is something like

```
Const balance = (Number(details[0].Balance) + 20).toString();
```

First, you need to ensure that the balance is a number, then add the 20 or the variable you want, and then convert it to a string. Then you can use that balance constant to send the data.